# Prepend a character to const char pointer C++

Tags: c++

Need to modify freeswitch to prepend a digit to a const char *

is it declared as:

```
const char *to;
```

to gets assigned as follows:

```
if (!(to = switch_event_get_header(event, "to_user"))) {
    to = switch_event_get_header(event, "to");
```

need to basically add "1" to in front of *to
Looking for some sample code...

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't modify a const string.  You need to copy it to a new string.

Comment: Why do you need `char` pointers? Why not use `std::string` which makes it so much easier to do what you want. And even with a C API you can use `std::string` in your own C++ code, and use the `c_str()` member function to get a pointer to its contained null-terminated string.

Comment: It is a pointer to `const char`, not a `const` pointer. So the assignment is legal. So you would allocate a new char array 2 larger than the length (`strlen`) of `to` (for the '1' and the `NUL`) with `new`, copy the old `to` to the new memory at offset 1, and set offset 0 to `1`. Deallocating the memory will be tricky, especially if existing code uses the pointer `to` for it. Without more knowledge of the existing code, you cannot create a safe and stable solution.